# Пытался установить отдельно PIL

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Хотел отдельно установить Pil, потому что при команде runserver выходила ошибка `cannot import name 'image' from 'PIL'`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вроде в python 3+ используется библиотека pillow `pip install --upgrade Pillow`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
python -m pip install pillow  
from PIL import Image
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install pillow #python 2
```

```
pip3 install pillow # python 3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
python3 -m pip install --upgrade Pillow
```

https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation.html